# Why is the Java G1 gc spending so much time scanning RS?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

I'm currently evaluating the G1 garbage collector and how it performs for our application. Looking at the gc-log, I noticed a lot of collections have very long "Scan RS" phases:

```
7968.869: [GC pause (mixed), 10.27831700 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 10080.8 ms]
   (...)
      [Scan RS (ms):  4030.4  4034.1  4032.0  4032.0
       Avg: 4032.1, Min: 4030.4, Max: 4034.1, Diff:   3.7]
      [Object Copy (ms):  6038.5  6033.3  6036.7  6037.1
       Avg: 6036.4, Min: 6033.3, Max: 6038.5, Diff:   5.2]
   (...)
    [Eden: 19680M(19680M)->0B(20512M) Survivors: 2688M->2624M Heap:
     75331M(111904M)->51633M(115744M)]
 [Times: user=40.49 sys=0.02, real=10.28 secs]
```

All the removed log-rows entries show runtimes in single-digit ms.

I think most of the time should be spent in copying, right? What could be the reason Scan RS takes so long? Any ideas on how to tweak the G1-settings?
The JVM was started with

```
-Xms40960M -Xmx128G -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log
```

Edit: Oh, I forgot... I'm using Java 7u25

**Update:**
I noticed two other weird things:

```
16187.740: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
16203.934: [GC pause (young), 2.89871800 secs]
(...)
16218.455: [GC pause (young), 4.61375100 secs]
(...)
16237.441: [GC pause (young), 4.46131800 secs]
(...)
16257.785: [GC pause (young), 4.73922600 secs]
(...)
16275.417: [GC pause (young), 3.87863400 secs]
(...)
16291.505: [GC pause (young), 3.72626400 secs]
(...)
16307.824: [GC pause (young), 3.72921700 secs]
(...)
16325.851: [GC pause (young), 3.91060700 secs]
(...)
16354.600: [GC pause (young), 5.61306000 secs]
(...)
16393.069: [GC pause (young), 17.50453200 secs]
(...)
16414.590: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 226.8497670 sec]
```

The concurrent GC run is continuing while parallel runs are being performed. I'm not sure if that's intended, but it kinda seems wrong to me. Admittedly, this is an extreme example, but I do see this behaviour all over my log.

Another thing is that my JVM process grew to 160g. Considering a heap-size of 128g, that's a rather large overhead. Is this to be expected, or is G1 leaking memory? Any ideas on how to find that out?

PS: I'm not really sure if I should've made new questions for the updates... if any of you think that this would be beneficial, tell me ;)

**Update 2:**
I guess the G1 really may be leaking memory: http://printfdebugger.tumblr.com/post/19142660766/how-i-learned-to-love-cms-and-had-my-heart-broken-by-g1
As this is a deal-breaker for now, I'm not going to spend more time on playing with this.
Things I didn't yet try is configuring region size (-XX:G1HeapRegionSize) and lowering the heap occupancy (-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent).

Comment: 160 GB? Wow! What are you working on?

Comment: In-memory planning/reporting for global supply-chains. Not saying the footprint couldn't be reduced, but it definitely can be a lot of data for large customers.

Comment: If you have that much memory it makes sense to utilize it. It's great JVM can handle that much (although I see your issues).

Answer (score 6):

Let's see.

**1 - First clues**

It looks like your GC was configured to use 4 threads (or you have 4 vCPU, but it is unlikely given the size of the heap). It is quite low for a 128GB heap, I was expecting more.

The GC events seems to happen at 25+ seconds interval. However, the log extract you gave do not mention the number of regions that were processed.

=> By any chance, did you specify pause time goals to G1GC (`-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=N`) ?

**2 - Long Scan RSet time**

"Scan RSet" means the time the GC spent in scanning the Remembered Sets. Remembered Set of a region contains cards that correspond to the references pointing into that region. This phase scans those cards looking for the references pointing into all the regions of the collection set.

So here, we have one more question :

=> How many regions were processed during that particular collection (i.e. how big is the CSet)

**3 - Long Object Copy time**

The copy time, as the name suggest, is the time spend by each worker thread copying live objects from the regions in the Collection Set to the other regions.

Such long copy time can suggest that a lot of regions were processed, and that you may want to reduce that number. It could also suggest swapping, but this is very unlikely given your user/real values at the end of the log.

**4 - Now what to do**

You should check in the GC log the number of regions that were processed. Correlate this number with your region size and deduce the amount of memory that was scanned.

You can then set a smaller pause time goal (for instance, to 500ms using `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500`). This will

- increase the number of GC events,
- reduce the amount of freed memory per GC cycle
- reduce the STW pauses during YGC

Hope that helps !

Sources :

- https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_g1_gc_logs
- http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html
- http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/

Comment: No additional command line switches, so the pause time goal should've been the standard 200ms. The JVM itself was running in a VM with 4 cores assigned (I think), the physical machine should definitely have more, so that's something to try. Currently the biggest deal-breaker is the memory overhead, so right now we're not looking further into G1.

Comment: According to the Oracle website, the footprint of G1 should be less than 6% of total memory, so < 8GB in your case. I agree with you that those 32GB overhead does not make any sense...

Comment: I have to admit I triggered a full GC via JVisualVM at some point. I think I read somewhere that those may lead to memory leaks... but then again, I saw huge memory increases a lot later in time, so I guess that wasn't the issue. Our own code doesn't make use of any native stuff or DirectMemoryBuffers, but there is a lot of persisting via JDBC done, and those libraries may do so. This may lead to leaking memory due to G1 not calling their finalizers (just a guess, but things like that are mentioned in my link above). Anyways, thanks for your help!